# Session in ASP is showing error

Tags: asp-classic

```
IF Session("days")> 1 then
```

this statement is not working in my Classic ASP code.Any help is greatly appreciated

Just I need to know whether this is a valid session code for Classic ASP (No error message is showing)

Comment: Classic ASP? ASP.NET? What version of IIS? What is the error you are getting? Does session work with other items? You need to provide lots more detail before anyone can help.

Comment: *Not working* is not a very precise problem description and definitely not enough to provide you with an answer in this case.

Comment: What is the exact error? Can you check the value of Session("days")?

Answer (score 5):

Most probably this is because 
Session("days") returns a string that you are using as integer.

This might fix the issue

```
If CINT(Session("days"))>1 Then
End If
```

Comment: Better yet make sure that at the point the Session variable is assigned it is of the correct type, then you won't have to worry about every where you use it.

Answer (score 0):

when saving the session variable do `session("var") = 1` not: `session("var") = "1"`

or:

```
 Dim svar as Integer
 svar = some integer
 session("var") = svar
```